# Import Excel in Access with custom dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have some trouble getting my import to work:

```
Function importMetrics() 
Dim strFile As String 
Dim strPath As String 
Dim strWorksheet As String 
Dim strTable As String 

'Excel variables 
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 
Dim xlFile As Excel.Workbook 
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet 
Dim xlRange1 As Excel.Range 
Dim xlRange2 As Excel.Range 

Dim r1, r2 As String 
Dim r#, c# 
Dim clVal As String

'Set File Path 
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Data\2015\01 - January" 

'check if directory exists 
If Len(Dir(strPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then 
    MsgBox ("File Doesn't exist") 
    End 
End If 

'Import all Files 
strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xl*") 

'ID which Sheet to Import 
strWorksheet = "EP & NBO DATA" 

'ID Table to Import To 
strTable = "tbl_MIPData" 

'start loop 
Do While strFile <> "" 
    'Open File 
    'Get the info from Excel: 
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application 

    Set xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strFile, False, True) 

    Set xlSheet = xlFile.Sheets(strWorksheet) 

    Set xlRange1 = xlSheet.Range("A1" & xlSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select 
    Set xlRange2 = xlSheet.Range("N1" & xlSheet.Range("N1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select 

    'Import File Range A 

     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _ 
        transfertype:=acImport, _ 
        tablename:=strTable, _ 
        FileName:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _ 
        hasFieldNames:=False, _ 
        Range:=xlRange1 

    'Import File Range B 
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _ 
        transfertype:=acImport, _ 
        tablename:=strTable, _ 
        FileName:=strPath & strFile, _ 
        hasFieldNames:=False, _ 
        Range:=strWorksheet & "!" & xlRange2 

        'Close Excel File 
        xlApp.Quit 
        Set xlApp = Nothing 
Loop 

End Function
```

This is the code I've written so far. I think it has to do with how I am opening the Excel files. The Range fails on `xlRange1` and `xlRange2`. If I put an `xlSheet.Select` it doesn't seem to fix it.

I am stumped at this point. In addition I couldn't find much on how to recursively walk the sub-directories (e.g. Walk all the Excel files in data)

Access 2010, with Excel 2010 XLSX files.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import the data whilst the file is open which will give you some issues.
What you want to do, is open the excel file, set your ranges, save the workbook, import your ranges, then go back in and clear the named ranges if you so wish.

If you are importing two separate sets of data stored in one worksheet, you may want to look at splitting them onto two separate worksheets to make your life much easier.

Currently though, Something like;

```
Do While strFile <> "" 
'Open File 
'Get the info from Excel: 
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application 

Set xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strFile, False, True) 

Set xlSheet = xlFile.Sheets(strWorksheet)
```

It's easier to use a variable to capture your last used row
such as

```
dim lastRow as integer
lastrow = xlSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown) 'set the value of our last used row
xlSheet.Range("A1:M" & lastRow & "").name = "xlRange1" 'apply a name to our range
lastrow = xlSheet.Range("n1").End(xlDown) 'reset our last row value
xlSheet.Range("N1:'enterlastcolumnhere'" & lastRow & "").name = "xlRange2"

xlFile.save 'save our named ranges
xlApp.Quit 'close off
Set xlApp = Nothing 



'Import File Range A 

 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _ 
    transfertype:=acImport, _ 
    tablename:=strTable, _ 
    FileName:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _ 
    hasFieldNames:=False, _ 
    Range:="xlRange1" 'this should now work if we didn't get any errors when setting the named ranges

'Import File Range B 
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _ 
    transfertype:=acImport, _ 
    tablename:=strTable, _ 
    FileName:=strPath & strFile, _ 
    hasFieldNames:=False, _ 
    Range:="xlRange2"
```

Loop

End Function

I have written the code changes from memory but this should put you on the right track, if you still get stuck with it let me know I can dig out a previous example I have written for you! HTH

Comment: I cannot modify the original worksheet as it is read only. I'll see if I can save the first and last rows and then see if it works.

Comment: If the worksheet is read only do a save as and then remove the read only property, import your data, then delete the copy would be a good approach to take

Comment: Found a solution. Had to open it twice. Transfer Spreadsheet wasn't going to work so I ended up opening it, finding the range, then using ACE to read the excel via SQL and doing an INSERT INTO with the results.

Answer (score 0):

- [TransferSpreadsheet Method [Access 2003 VBA Language Reference]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220766%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

> **Range** *Optional Variant*. A *string* expression that's a valid range of cells or the *name* of a range in the spreadsheet. This argument applies only to importing. Leave this argument blank to import the entire spreadsheet.
>   
>   As above text you need the range to be like `B2:F10` instead of parsing a `Range` object.

So you can use `Address` property of your ranges like:

```
Range:=xlRange1.Address
```

I can't test it.